# How to maintain a link between parent QStandardItems and database row ids in a tree model?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a little problem I am trying to figure out, I am working on a QT app that is using the QTreeView and I have a bunch of categories which have children, so they look like

```
Parent 1
Parent 2
  - Child 1
  - Child 2
Parent 3
```

and so on and so forth, so in my database I have rows which have all the regular details (name, id, date created, etc) and the ones which are children have their parent specified (so pid=parent row id). I then loop over then using the standard QSqlQuery stuff. But the problem I am running into is this...

Items are added to the treeview by `QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(icon, name);` and then appending the row `model->appendRow(item);` but my children need to call `parentitem->appendRow(item);` so the `QStandardItem* item` of the parent. But how can I find out what that is without storing every single `item`?

Moral of the story is, is there a way to do one of the following that won't destroy performance.

1. Store the `QStandardItem* item` in an array that I could reference the parent in the childs loop?
2. Assign an ID or something to `QStandardItem* item` which I could then reference when adding a child.
3. Generate a TreeView model from an array, where the children array elements get added as children?
4. Something else I haven't thought of...

I can't seem to find any good examples of QTreeView with children from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a `QMap<int, QStandardItem*> rowItemMap`. When you retrieve a row from the database with a given row id, you immediately create an item and add it to the map. You then add it to a parent that you look up in the map. You'll need to create a dummy parent as the root item. There's nothing wrong with storing pointers to items. For reasonable amounts of items, it won't matter. If you think of storing more than 10k items, you may want to think of using a view that offers transitive closure up to a certain depth of the tree. It'd then be much easier to map such a view, via `QSqlTableModel`, directly onto the tree, without having to copy the entire tree from the database into a temporary model.